# php.ini $_POST empty for unknown reason (localhost)

Tags: php, config

I usually automatically uploaded the scripts and test them on the remote hosting, but few days ago I installed the magic trio Apache, PHP and MySQL each one independently to test small problems faster. Today it came out that the $_POST array is totally empty. It's a basic form the one I'm testing and it perfectly works on the remote hosting, so I checked the php.ini file. I found that the `enable_post_data_reading` was set on Off and commented (although the documentation says it's enabled by default). I thought that was the problem but no. I restarted Apache and even the notebook but the $_POST array is still empty, outputing `Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\Users\Marco\Proj\untitled\insert.php on line 3`.
Do anyone has **any suggestion**?
(I'm passing just strings, so the problem is not even the `post_max_size` option) 
Thanks!

Although it's useless I anyway post the code

form.html

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" style="display:block" />
  <input type="text" name="code" value="" placeholder="code" style="display:block" />
  <input type="text" name="price" placeholder="price" style="display:block" />
  <label>Show</label><input type="checkbox" name="show" value="checked" />
  <input type="submit" value="inserisci" style="display: block" />
</form>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
include "filterFunctions.php";
$data = array("name" => $_POST["name"],
              "code" => $_POST["code"],
              "price" => $_POST["price"],
              "checkbox" => $_POST["show"]);
print_r($_POST);
```

*[EDIT]* Following **Swatantra K**'s advice I checked if POST works using `echo file_get_contents('php://input');` and this is what it displays:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarysqxwAAdf3E55NZUK Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name" Marco 
------WebKitFormBoundarysqxwAAdf3E55NZUK Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code" 35DW 
------WebKitFormBoundarysqxwAAdf3E55NZUK Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price" 99,9 
------WebKitFormBoundarysqxwAAdf3E55NZUK Content-Disposition: form-data; name="show" checked 
------WebKitFormBoundarysqxwAAdf3E55NZUK-- 

Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\Users\Marco\Proj\untitled\insert.php on line 4
Notice: Undefined index: code in C:\Users\Marco\Proj\untitled\insert.php on line 5
Notice: Undefined index: price in C:\Users\Marco\Proj\untitled\insert.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: show in C:\Users\Marco\Proj\untitled\insert.php on line 7
Array ( )
```

It means, I guess, that it works and that the inserted values exist, but I still can't figure out what's the problem and its solution. Also because `var_dump($_POST);`  still displays `array(0) { }`.
Any clue?

Comment: What does the `filterFunctions.php` file do?

Comment: Is `$_POST` is an array? I didn't know this.

Comment: What is your postmax_size value?

Comment: You have `name` twice in your form, but it should still show. Try `var_dump($_POST)` and `var_dump($_REQUEST)` before your include line.

Comment: @JiriHrazdil it will filter and sanitize the strings, but I still didn't write it (I didn't even call the function) 'cause I stopped due to this "stupid" problem that I don't know where comes from

Comment: @MuhammadAsif It was 10M and I set it to 128M

Comment: Commented directives in `php.ini` don't take effect. But you don't have to figure out directive from config files and documentation; run time values can be retrieved with `ini_get()` or (easier) `phpinfo()`. You also don't need to guess what `$_POST` contains, you can inspect any PHP variable with `var_dump()`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Sure, I in fact used `var_dump()` and it was `false` for all the $_POST

Comment: @aynber You're right, it was just a copy-paste error ;) I tried `var_dump($_POST)` but displays an empty array (0). The same for `var_dump($_REQUEST)`

Comment: You are missing a `>` at the end of your closing `form` tag. Not sure if that is the cause. Also, do you check in your dev tools to make sure that the request is being sent as a POST request? What do you get if you do `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`? It should be POST.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Another copy-paste error, gonna edit it. What do you mean? If I specify the `method="post"` in the `<form>` it should send the data as POST, and with `$_POST` I have always been able to get it (apart now on the localhost!). Probably I didn't understand what you meant

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` display, `false` or `array(0)`? How about `enable_post_data_reading`? Can you edit the question and display the information there?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I set `enable_post_data_reading = On` but it didn't solve anything, that's why I asked here on Stack; while `var_dump($_POST)` displays `array(0) { }`. I edited the question using `echo file_get_contents('php://input');`, probably you can help me with that

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
php_value post_max_size = 256M
```

or check if POST works

```
echo file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: I set `post_max_size` to 256 but nothing changed, while the `echo file_get_contents('php://input');` doesn't produce any output; it means it doesn't work?

Comment: HTTP POST data is usually populated in $_POST, php://input will usually contain PUT data.

Comment: Ok there's a semi-good news! I tried again with `echo file_get_contents('php://input');` and it outputs: `------WebKitFormBoundarysqxwAAdf3E55NZUK Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name" Marco ------WebKitFormBoundarysqxwAAdf3E55NZUK Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code" 35DW ------WebKitFormBoundarysqxwAAdf3E55NZUK Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price" 99,9 ------WebKitFormBoundarysqxwAAdf3E55NZUK Content-Disposition: form-data; name="show" checked ------WebKitFormBoundarysqxwAAdf3E55NZUK-- ` with all the insert data, but right after it outputs: `Undefined index: XXX` for all

Comment: @brigo somehow I missed the thread. Did you manage to get it?

Comment: @SwatantraK Fortunately you answered! Unfortunately I didn't solve the problem 'cause I didn't get from where it comes from and I think you're the one who could understand it. I also tried to download php7 again and even substituing it with php5 but the problem is always there. Do you have any clue of why with `file_get_contents('php://input');` the POST datas seem to have been passed but with `$_POST` no?

Answer (score 0):

you have two input field with name="name" so  you are refering to both of these fields in php script, so remove one from it ,  and also define type attribute for form and assign value multipart. Hope this may work.

Comment: You're right, but the doubled name was just a copy-paste error, I edited the question. What do you mean with "assign value multipart"? Assign a blank `value=" "`?

Comment: i mean use enctype="multipart/form-data"  attribute in form element .

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem but I'm gonna use it now on when I use the POST method, thanks ;)